# Create borderbrush "around the border path"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, brush

I'm trying to create a border with a gradient stroke *around the border path*, not around the full element but around the border itself.

A simple example of what I do not want is:

```
<Border BorderThickness="10" Width="100" Height="50">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
</Border>
```

This creates a border that looks like:

[image]

What I to achieve wish is something like the image below. Notice that this achieved by blurring, I rather not do that as that would limit the what can be done - and more importantly: it would either blur all child elements, or I'd lose the ability to walk the visual tree with the border at the expected position. (Border would be a sibbling to its "content")

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put an outer Border around the inner one?

Comment: @mm8 What would that achieve? - Blurring is not the way I wish to go as it limits in what can be achieved: I can't "blur from blue to red".

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "around the border path" then.

Comment: @mm8 - as in the image: the gradient "direction" would be perpendicular to the path direction. - And the gradient origin would be at the path edge.

Comment: You might have some luck with the [`PathGradientBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-path-gradient) instead of a `LinearGradientBrush`.

Comment: Maybe you can give us more detail and explain, Why you don't want to use Bluring? Could be that question is the root of your problem

Comment: @ASpirin To have more control: a blur is a "magical operation". Take the example below (or the one in my post): the blurring is uncontrolled and that means that (for example) the corners (due to gaussian formula) are "darker" than the rest. - While a simple path brush would have behave like a simple formula colour = f(d), with d the distance to the path, and I'd (ultimately) would like to give any function for f to have perfect control - and, say, use additive blend instead of alpha channels).

Answer (score 2):

Dig a bit into `shadow` of border it looks closer

```
<Border BorderThickness="5" Width="100" Height="50" CornerRadius="5"  BorderBrush="Gray">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Opacity="1" ShadowDepth="1" Color="Black">
        </DropShadowEffect>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
```

It will give you something like

[image]

**Alternatively**

you can draw Blured `dummy` border on the same place with the current one (Bind width and height), but lower in the markup, in that case UI will draw `dummy` border over your container border and you'll see bluring without harming the tree

```
<Border BorderThickness="0" Width="100" Height="50" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Gray" x:Name="x">
    <TextBox Width="70" Height="20">Some data</TextBox>
</Border>
<Border BorderThickness="5" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=x}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=x}" CornerRadius="0" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Border.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="10"></BlurEffect>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with those methods, is that I can't use a custom function for the blur/shadow. Especially the problem is that blurring/shadow only goes from a single color "transparant". (Whereas with a linear gradient I can approximate any function and any number of colors by adding a lot of points)

Comment: For shadow you can use another color

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to be able to have a blurred gradient border i think you might have to go with something like this.

1. Create a trapeze-shape with your gradient:

[image: trapeze-shape]

2. Then copy this shape 3 times and apply some render-transformations to get the border shape
   [image: border-shape]
3. Apply a Blur Effect on the whole shape

[image]

I made all those screenshots directly from the WPF result.